# jquery onclick from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had this problem here [javascript - Need onclick to go full distance before click works again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896860/javascript-need-onclick-to-go-full-distance-before-click-works-again) that I couldn't seem to figure out how to make it work. So I am going on to plan B which is to try to go from div to div within a scroll. Currently, my HTML looks something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="outerwrapper">
    <div class="innerwrapper">
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <div id="left">
    <div id="right">
</div>
```

Javscript

```
$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".outerwrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

So currently I was trying to get it to move the full 251px first before another click event could fire. The problem is when a user clicks on the arrow multiple times, it resets the event and starts over from within the scroll so instead of going from frame to frame, it could start in the middle of the frame and end in the middle of the frame. Since I haven't been able to figure out how to make the javascript complete its action first so it goes the full 261 px before the event can happen again, I was wondering is there a way to transition from div to div so the user can click as many times as they like and it will transition smoothly from div to div and not end up in the middle once its done?

Comment: Calling `.stop()` will immediately stop the animation, even if the animation has not yet completed (resulting in a mid-move cancellation in your case). You could remove the `.stop()` altogether or instruct it to jump to the end of the animation with `.stop(false, true);`.

Comment: this works but makes it jump to the next one, is there no way to have it not jump?

Comment: You want to look into jquery's `deferred` call.  It lets you chain a bunch of actions together.  You could use it in your js function to add a new event when any currently running ones complete.  Just search for "jquery deferred", and also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119208/how-to-use-queue-or-deferred-in-what-condition-what-are-their-designing-pur

Comment: yeah I looked up deferred, but it works for succession commands, I wasn't trying to do that

Comment: I answered your other question (and provided a jsfiddle) that solves the same problem and it seems to be working fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18966254/1937302

Answer (score 3):

That's what `on()` and `off()` are for :

```
$(function () {
    var buttons = $("#right, #left");
    buttons.on('click', ani);

    function ani()
        buttons.off('click');

        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".outerwrapper").animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000, function() {
            buttons.on('click', ani);
        });
    }
});
```

Another option would be to not rely on the currently scrolled position, but a variable you keep track of yourself.

```
$(function () {
    $("#right, #left").on('click', function() {
        var wrap = $(".outerwrapper"),
            dir  = this.id == "right" ? 251 : -251,
            Left = (wrap.data('scroller') || 0)  + (dir);

        $(".outerwrapper").animate({ scrollLeft: Left }, 1000);
        wrap.data('scroller', Left);
    });
});
```

Comment: this completely shuts off the clicking ability

Comment: sorry let me try something one second

Comment: Yes, until the animation has completed? Either you stop the animation, or you stop further clicking, or you use exact values in your animation instead of the horrible `+=` and `-=`

Comment: well the point of the += and -= is for scrolling ability though

Comment: unfortunately now the left and right arrow buttons don't even work

Comment: maybe because the animate isn't there anymore

Comment: Did you try closing the elements for those arrows ?

Comment: yeah i see it works there, but when I put it into my JS page, I refresh the page and the JS doesn't work anymore anywhere in the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37902/discussion-between-keith-and-adeneo)