# How to chain .call() functions - adding transitions to Nivo Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, nivo-slider

I'm trying to impliment CSS animation transitions for items displayed in a Nivo Lightbox. 
I've got the new function inserted and running, but the 2 following functions run before it is complete.

```
$('.nivo-lightbox-prev').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                
    var index = galleryItems.index(currentLink);
    currentLink = galleryItems.eq(index - 1);
    if(!$(currentLink).length) currentLink = galleryItems.last();
    $this.options.beforePrev.call(this, [ currentLink ]);  # <---- new function I added
    $this.processContent(content, currentLink);            # <---- existing function 1
    $this.options.onPrev.call(this, [ currentLink ]);      # <---- existing function 2
});
```

The only way I know would be to put them in a callback, but .call() doesn't accept a callback.

I tried this:

```
function beforePrev(callback){
    $this.options.beforePrev.call(this, [ currentLink ]);
    callback();
}
function onPrev(){
    $this.processContent(content, currentLink);
    $this.options.onPrev.call(this, [ currentLink ]);
}
beforePrev(onPrev);
```

but it behaved the same.

In case it's relevant the code for beforePrev is:

```
beforePrev: function() {
    el = $('.nivo-lightbox-content');
    el.addClass('animated fadeOutLeft');
    el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function (e) {
        el.removeClass('fadeOutLeft');
    });
},
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Update / edit for extra clarity:
This is the full original Nivo code: [link](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Lightbox/blob/master/nivo-lightbox.js)

From my reading of it, `$this` is just a standard variable referring to the init function, not a DOM object. I think this is one of the reasons this seems hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out deferind / promise is the key here, using jQuery's .when(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

This answer: [How to use "queue" or "deferred" in what condition? What are their designing purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119208/how-to-use-queue-or-deferred-in-what-condition-what-are-their-designing-pur) helped - .queue() is primarily for animations and acts on a DOM object, whereas .deferred() is for async operations.

So in this example:

```
$('.nivo-lightbox-prev').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = galleryItems.index(currentLink);
    currentLink = galleryItems.eq(index - 1);
    if(!$(currentLink).length) currentLink = galleryItems.last();
    $.when($this.options.beforePrev.call(this, [ currentLink ])).done(function(){
        $this.processContent(content, currentLink);
        $this.options.onPrev.call(this, [ currentLink ]);
    });
});
```

Then in the beforePrev function, start by setting up a .deferred() object, then .resolve() when it is complete, and finally pass the .promise() back:

```
beforePrev: function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    el = $('.nivo-lightbox-content');
    el.addClass('fastAnimated fadeOutRight');
    el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function (e) {
        el.removeClass('fadeOutRight');
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

In order to execute function b only after function a has completed it's execution:

```
$('element').a()
.queue(function() {
   $('element').b();
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kapantzak - that looked like it would work but I couldn't get it to.

I **think** the problem is that `$this` refers to the init object?? (this is the full Nivo code: [link](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Lightbox/blob/master/nivo-lightbox.js) )